# nosql beginner question

Tags: nosql

what is the best documented and stable version of nosql technology to use with python or maybe with another programming languages ? 
Are there any good tutorials ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two most popular are MongoDB and Redis.

If you have a specialized need there are other choices that are better. But in general those two is what most people want.

Answer (score 1):

There is no unique "NoSQL" solution which fits all requirements. You need to provide more information on what you want to achieve so we can guide into a specific direction.

Nonetheless here are some good databases (which all target a different market actually):

MongoDB, CouchDB, Redis, Cassandra, Riak